# limit double at six decimal place in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, decimal-point

i have a double, the decimal place isn't fix (8-?)

i want to fix the decimal place to six  (for example: 1,234567).

this is my double:

```
CStr(score)
```

i guess it's quiet simple :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
score.ToString("0.000000")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also `Math.Round(3.44, 1) 'Returns 3.4.`

[Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After Decimal point Add Zero's like this

Dim tot as String
Dim totAmt as Double
totAmt=10.10
tot=String.Format("{0:00.000}", totAmt)
OutPut: 10.100

After Decimal point Remove Zero's like this

totAmt=10.750
tot=Math.Round(totAmt,2)
Output:10.75

Sloved